# STUFF function in SQL Server and in ORACLE

Tags: sql-server, oracle8i

I have two `STUFF` questions for this topic.

First question is `STUFF` function in SQL Server. 2nd question is about the `STUFF` function in Oracle (8i).

Question 1: How can I remove the `,` from the column I want to stuff?

Example, given table:

```
ID      Country     Payment     Product
12345       USA     Cash        Red wine
12345       USA     Cash    
12345       USA     Cash
```

Using this script, it produces:

```
select distinct Country, Payment,
stuff(isnull((select ', ' + x.Product from #temp x where x.ID = t.ID
group by x.Product for xml path ('')), ''), 1, 2, '') as Product


ID      Country     Payment     Product
12345   USA         Cash       , Red wine
```

How can I remove result to show just `Red wine` only (remove the comma (,)?

PLEASE NOTE: I did not write this `STUFF` function. It is written by someone named OMG Ponies.

Question 2: Same as question 1 but the syntax is in Oracle:

```
select distinct ID, Country, Payment, WM_CONCAT(Product) AS Products
from
(
select distinct ID, Country, Payment, Product
from temp table
)x
group by ID, Country, Payment
```

I would like my result to show just `Red wine` only (remove the comma (,).

Comment: This seems to me like it should be two separate questions.

Comment: Yes, it is two seperate questions as stated

Comment: A question on StackOverflow can only have one "best" or "accepted" answer. This one is likely going to have two, because the odds that one person is going to post the right answer to both of your questions is small. I strongly suggest making a separate question for the Oracle problem.

Comment: For background, [I just brought this up on meta yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143568/how-to-deal-with-splintered-questions).

Comment: I see. Got your point. Thanks. Will apply that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:** 
As far as the SQL Server part of the answer it looks like you have empty strings in your Product field - they are not nulls if there is not one. So you can use the following.  I added the line `and (product != '' and product is not null)` to your `Stuff()` part and it will remove the extra comma:

```
select distinct Country, Payment,
    stuff(isnull((select ', ' + x.Product 
                    from test x 
                    where x.ID = t.ID 
                      and (product != '' and product is not null)
                    group by x.Product for xml path ('')), ''), 1, 2, '') as Product
from test t
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af2df/2)

**Question 2:** I do not have access to an Oracle 8i version but I am going to guess that if you exclude the values with the empty string the comma will disappear.

Comment: THANK YOU bluefeet! I just tested it. It works perfectly! Thanks again.